# jQuery reading multiple XML files and remove duplicates when inserting into HTML for Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a total of 4 XML files in same format representing 4 different categories of project contents. However some projects does have more than 1 category.

I want to merge all 4 XML files using jQuery and display all projects contents in a single page within a , but due to the fact that some projects have more than 1 category, the displayed results show duplicates of project contents.

How do I remove duplicates within the combined extracted XML files?

Here is my jQuery Code:

```
XMLLIST = {

//general settings
xml1: 'xml/structural_steel.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
xml2: 'xml/building_work_id.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
xml3: 'xml/shear_stud_welding.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
xml4: 'xml/custom_solution.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
appendTo: '#list', //set the id/class to insert XML data

init: function () {

    //jQuery ajax call to retrieve the XML file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLLIST.xml1,
        dataType: "xml",            
        success: XMLLIST.parseXML
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLLIST.xml2,
        dataType: "xml",            
        success: XMLLIST.parseXML
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLLIST.xml3,
        dataType: "xml",            
        success: XMLLIST.parseXML
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLLIST.xml4,
        dataType: "xml",            
        success: XMLLIST.parseXML
    }); 

}, // end: init()

parseXML: function (xml) {

    //Grab every single ITEM tags in the XML file
    var data;
    data = $('item', xml).get();        

    var i = 1;

    //Loop through all the ITEMs
    $(data).each(function () {

        //Parse data and embed it with HTML
        XMLLIST.insertHTML($(this));

        i++;
    });

}, // end: parseXML()

insertHTML: function (item) {

    //retrieve each of the data field from ITEM
    var url = item.find('url').text();
    var image = item.find('image').text();
    var title = item.find('title').text();
    var html;

    //Embed them into HTML code
    html = '<div class="item">';
    html += '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '"></a><br>';
    html += '<span class="contentsubtitle">' + title + '</span><br><br>';
    html += '</div>';

    //Append it to user predefined element
    $(html).appendTo(XMLLIST.appendTo);

}, // end: insertHTML()        


}

//Run this script
XMLLIST.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my code is correct. Had no data to test with, but I think the idea of it should be a bit more clear.

**edited:** Now working, version after receiving xml test-data

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdasd</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="list">

        </div>
        <script>
            XMLLIST = {
                dataToLoad: [
                    'test.xml'
                ],
                loadedData: [],
                appendTo: '#list',
                rand: function() {
                    return new Date().getTime();
                },
                loadData: function(file) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: file + "?" + XMLLIST.rand(),
                        dataType: "xml",            
                        success: XMLLIST.parseXML,
                        error: function(r) {
                            console.error(r);
                        }
                    }); 
                },
                init: function () {
                    XMLLIST.dataToLoad.forEach(function(file) {
                        XMLLIST.loadData(file);
                    });
                },
                parseXML: function (xml) {
                    var data = $('item', xml).get();
                    $(data).each(function (i, value) {
                        var $value = $(value),
                            item = {
                                url: $value.find('url').text(),
                                image: $value.find('image').text(),
                                title: $value.find('title').text()
                            };

                        if (!XMLLIST.itemIsInList(item)) {
                            XMLLIST.loadedData.push(item);
                            XMLLIST.insertHTML(item);
                        }
                    });
                },
                itemIsInList: function(item) {
                    var hits = XMLLIST.loadedData.filter(function(value){
                        return XMLLIST.compareItem(item, value);
                    });
                    return hits.length > 0
                },
                compareItem: function(item1, item2) {
                    return item1.url === item2.url && item1.image === item2.image && item1.title === item2.title;
                },
                insertHTML: function (item) {
                    var html = '<div class="item">';
                    html += '<a href="' + item.url + '"><img src="' + item.image + '"></a><br>';
                    html += '<span class="contentsubtitle">' + item.title + '</span><br><br>';
                    html += '</div>';
                    $(html).appendTo(XMLLIST.appendTo);
                }
            };
            XMLLIST.init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You have a list, where you push your objects to. This list has a checkFunction "itemIsInList". Additionally you need a seperate check-function "compareItem", because indexOf won't work with objects

Comment: Tested, but nothing displayed. Can explain your purpose of the
    rand: function() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    },

Comment: Sample XML Data:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>

 <item>
  <url>project1.html</url>
  <image>images/project1.jpg</image>
  <title>Project 1</title>
 </item> 

 <item>
  <url>project2.html</url>
  <image>images/project2.jpg</image>
  <title>Project 2</title>
 </item> 

 <item>
  <url>project3.html</url>
  <image>images/project3.jpg</image>
  <title>Project 3</title>
 </item> 

 <item>
  <url>project4.html</url>
  <image>images/project4.jpg</image>
  <title>Project 4</title>
 </item> 

</items>

Comment: Tried various method. But cannot get the answer to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: The purpose of the rand-function is to ALWAYS receive a unique number. Math.random() CAN (VERY VERY VERY RARE :D) output two identical numbers, timestamp not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to modify my original script by adding a masterArr for comparison of duplicated data received accross the 4 XMLs.

Here's the codes:

```
XMLLIST = {

    //general settings
    xml1: 'xml/structural_steel.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
    xml2: 'xml/building_work_id.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
    xml3: 'xml/shear_stud_welding.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
    xml4: 'xml/custom_solution.xml?' + Math.random(0,1), //solve ie weird caching issue
    appendTo: '#list', //set the id/class to insert XML data
    //end general settings

    masterArr: [],
    init: function () {

        //jQuery ajax call to retrieve the XML file
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XMLLIST.xml1,
            dataType: "xml",            
            success: XMLLIST.parseXML
        }); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XMLLIST.xml2,
            dataType: "xml",            
            success: XMLLIST.parseXML
        }); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XMLLIST.xml3,
            dataType: "xml",            
            success: XMLLIST.parseXML
        }); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XMLLIST.xml4,
            dataType: "xml",            
            success: XMLLIST.parseXML
        }); 

    }, // end: init()

    parseXML: function (xml) {

        //Grab every single ITEM tags in the XML file
        var data;
        data = $('item', xml).get();

        var i = 1;

        //Loop through all the ITEMs
        $(data).each(function () {

            //Check if masterArr[] already contains a duplicate of the item by checking using the XML label <image> or any other value/label that is unique. 
            //Insert into masterArr[] if not duplicate and publish HTML if not duplicate.
            var string1 = $(this).find('image').text();
            if( jQuery.inArray(string1, XMLLIST.masterArr) == -1){
                XMLLIST.masterArr.push(string1);
                //Parse data and embed it with HTML
                XMLLIST.insertHTML($(this));            
            };

            //If it reached user predefined total of display item, stop the loop, job done.
            //if (i == XMLLIST.display) return false;
            i++;
        });


    }, // end: parseXML()


    insertHTML: function (item) {

        //retrieve each of the data field from ITEM
        var url = item.find('url').text();
        var image = item.find('image').text();
        var title = item.find('title').text();
        var html;

        //Embed them into HTML code
        html = '<div class="item">';
        html += '<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '"></a><br>';
        html += '<span class="contentsubtitle">' + title + '</span><br><br>';
        html += '</div>';

        //Append it to user predefined element
        $(html).appendTo(XMLLIST.appendTo);

    }, // end: insertHTML()

}

//Run this script
XMLLIST.init();
```